# Go template examples

Tags: templates, go

What website has some good, up to date resources on using Go html/templates, especially in regard to parsing html files and handling lists? I came across the [Hoka Poka website](http://go.hokapoka.com/templates/), but it seems to be out of date.

Comment: Do you mean `text/template` or `html/template`?

Comment: For either one the unit tests in the source distribution are probably good exmaples.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

http://jan.newmarch.name/go/ and http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/go-templates.html

Comment: The last one has been updated to reflect the latest changes to the template package and also explain template sets.

Comment: @JohnDoe, template sets are now obsolete in bleeding edge.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: As of latest weekly or tip? Can you give me one keyword to browse the help for? Because the set functionality (eg. .Add) is still in.

Comment: As of [http://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=45e3c28dc7b5848e4577bed1b96f133be0969733](Nov 23, 2011) on trunk, the `Set` type no longer exists.

Answer (score 5):

[Google App Engine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html) have a simple example showing how to use `template` to render list with `range`.

Answer (score 5):

For "html/template", there are snippets of template code in the doc at http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/html/template/doc.go#83

> Contexts
>
> Assuming {{.}} is `O'Reilly: How are <i>you</i>?`, the table below shows
>   how {{.}} appears when used in the context to the left.
>
> ```
> Context                          {{.}} After
> {{.}}                            O'Reilly: How are &lt;i&gt;you&lt;/i&gt;?
> <a title='{{.}}'>                O&#39;Reilly: How are you?
> <a href="/{{.}}">                O&#39;Reilly: How are %3ci%3eyou%3c/i%3e?
> ```

and the test suite has many examples: https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/html/template/escape_test.go

To see templates in action, look at the `godoc` source code.
http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/cmd/godoc/godoc.go#642 is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.zmxv.com/2011/09/go-template-examples.html has a list of code snippets for the new Go template package.

Comment: These examples are for `template` not `html/template`.